# Releasing LINQ-to-SQL resources to avoid OutOfMemoryException

Tags: linq-to-sql, out-of-memory

## Background

Ok so I've got a simple LINQ-to-SQL DataContext with one table, containing about 900mb worth of PDF documents in a VARBINARY field, along with some other identifiers. `DeferredLoadingEnabled` is set to `true`. The point of the code is to export all the documents to PDF files on our server.

This isn't the first time I've done bulk "script" like stuff using linq-to-sql. It's a great tool for simply iterating over many records.

## Problem

My problem is after approx **1400** iterations of my `foreach (var c in ctx.Documents)` which takes the `Report` field and uses `File.WriteAllBytes(docName, c.Report.ToArray());` to write it to disk, I get an `OutOfMemoryException`.

As this is an internal piece of code, I simply used a `.Skip(1426)` on my selection and it finished successfully. Needless to say, when observing my program crash, I had indeed run out of memory.

*Are there any good ways to avoid this in the future*, or is LINQ-to-SQL bound by this restriction?

**One possible answer** I can think of is to set an iteration limit and re-instanciate my DataContext every 500 records or so. Doesn't sound very neat though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with ObjectChangeTracking turned off (readonly mode)?

Comment: yes that has actually done it. FYI I disabled DeferredLoadingEnabled and had to slightly modify my DBML file to disabled "Delay Loaded" on my large fields. Quick question, what if I *did* want to modify it? Would it be acceptable to run an "update this" routine and pass in the ID, then use another datacontext to do the update work? Perhaps in batches?